# Donut tutorial level 3 part 3: Why the half of my cup disappears when rendering the scene?

Tags: rendering

I following the donut tutorial level 3 part 3 where I am asked do a rendering image of the cup.

From the camera perspective it looks like this
[image]

But when I render it half of the cup has disappeared in the plate
[image]

How do I solve this? You can find my file here: https://blend-exchange.com/b/86QL38Kz

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Answer (score 2):

Your first screenshot of the *3D Viewport* is not the scene you have rendered. It's not the plate hiding the cup, the render doesn't even show the plate - it's below the plane. In your file you have moved the plane upwards so it's halfway in the cup - that's why everything is hidden below.

EDIT: If you only move the plate with the cup (parented to the plate) upwards instead of the plane downwards, they will be back under the plane as soon as you render or play an animation, because the plate has keyframes on location, rotation and scale which place it below the plane.

Your *3D Viewport* when I open your file:

[image: cup1]

Side view in *Wireframe* mode:

[image: cup2]

Comment: Hi Gordon :) 

It still happens when I adjust the cup. I just did it with the same result.

Comment: That's weird, I tried it as well and it works fine for me if I place cup higher or plane lower

Comment: @Maaske Have you tried adjusting the plane? Because your plate has got a keyframe for location, rotation and scale, so whereever you move it, it will jump right back for the render or if you start the animation. And since the cup is parented to the plate, it will move with it. There's also a keyframe on the plane material and the light... is that on purpose or by accident?

Comment: @MikoCG Placing the cup higher will not get the plate above the plane... and if you move the plate up, it will jump back below the plane because of the location keyframe.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thanks that sounds like it could be the case. Do you know how to adjust the keyframe?

Comment: Do you need the keyframes? If not, just delete them all... select the plate, in the _Timeline_ window make sure all keyframes are selected by hitting _A_, then _X_ > _Delete Keyframes_. Stupid question on my behalf: even if you keep the keyframes, would it be so terrible to just move the plane down?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank for the help. I did move the plane down but everytime I did the rendering it would go back up. But now it is fixed